# How to pass in HTML latitude and longitude into google reverse geocode to generate JSON data?

Tags: ajax, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-geolocation

I'm trying to generate geolocation data (Readable address) based on HTML lat/long data.

I'm not able to request for a JSON output from google maps api with the following. Nothing is returned in the console window. I'm mainly trying to pass the HTML lat/long params into ajax block. Is it a syntax error having just the "pos" within the url line? Any suggestion would be appreciated.

```
<body>
<div>
  <p>Click the button to get your coordinates.</p>

  <button onclick="getLocation()">Show Location</button>

  <p id="demo"></p>
</div>  
  <script>
  var x = document.getElementById("demo");

  function getLocation() {
      if (navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
      } else { 
          x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
      }
  }

  function showPosition(position) {
      x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
      "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
  }
</script>
// Try HTML5 geolocation.
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var pos = {
            lat: position.coords.latitude,
            lng: position.coords.longitude
        };

<div id="map"></div>
        <script>

          var map, infoWindow;

          function initMap() {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
              center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
              zoom: 12
            });
            infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

            // Try HTML5 geolocation.
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
              navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                var pos = {
                  lat: position.coords.latitude,
                  lng: position.coords.longitude
                };

                infoWindow.setPosition(pos);

                infoWindow.setContent('Location found.');

                infoWindow.open(map);
                map.setCenter(pos);

              }, function() {
                handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
              });
            } else {
              // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
              handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
            }
          }

          function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
            infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
            infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
                                  'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
                                  'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
            infoWindow.open(map);
          }
        </script>    

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=************&callback=initMap">

        </script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">

        $.ajax({

          url: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+pos+"&key=*********",
          type: "GET",
          success: function (data) {
            console.log(data)

          }

        })
        </script>
```

Update****Added all codes within *****

Comment: Does it show any errors?

Comment: That isn't valid javascript, there is a missing `}`

Comment: Shouldn't the upper half of code reside inside `<script>... </script>` tag??

Comment: Your request is in the wrong format, should be (from the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start#reverse)): `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

Comment: The jquery include is in the wrong place.

Comment: -Jose, no errors shown.

Comment: -geocodezip, i added all codes within <body>

Comment: You have javascript code not enclosed in `script` tags. You should add jQuery script tag at the top of the document. Also, you're making the ajax call before actually knowing the current position which, BTW, must be passed to google geocode API like @geocodezip said. See this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/amenadiel/k8fjhycc/13/

Comment: - amenadiel - works great! Thanks!